# How can I copy every contact I listed in block event invites to block app invites on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

On https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=blocking I would like to copy every contact I listed in `block event invites` to `block app invites`. Is there any way to do so at once?

[image]